# Change css class of loop values in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following

```
echo "<span>".apply_filters(" $value\n", $value)."</span>";
```

that outputs

```
<span>Value</span> <span>value 2</span> <span>value 3</span>
```

I want to append a 1 to each span outputted, so

```
<span class="span-1">Value</span> <span"span-2">value 2</span> <span"span-3">value 3</span>
```

How would I go about doing this or when can I find information/correct terminology on the issue?

Thanks

---

```
foreach ( (array) $keys as $key ) {
    $keyt = trim($key);
    if ( '_' == $keyt{0} || 'pricing' == $keyt || 'vehicleType' == $keyt || 'coverageRegion' == $keyt || 'locationType' == $keyt )
    continue;
    $values = array_map('trim', get_post_custom_values($key));
    $value = implode($values,', '); 
    echo "<span class='srch-val'>".apply_filters(" $value\n", $value)."</span>";
}
```

Comment: We would have to know what your `apply_filters` function is doing.

Comment: please, add source of apply_filters function

Comment: `apply_filters` is a wordpress-function. You should add a wordpress-tag..;) And I think you should edit the `apply_filters` itself, or write your own function...

Comment: snaderss - agree that it's likely wordpress, but - we can't know until told - it could just be custom function he wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to jQuery, you can use jQuery functions to change the class names of whichever classes you'd like using addClass() and removeClass(). There's also a .css() method that allows you you to change your css on specific elements of groups of elements.

This is the documentation for addClass: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `foreach ($key=>$value) {}` loop with a numeric key starting from 0:

```
echo '<span class="span-'.$key.'">'.apply_filters(" $value\n", $value).'</span>';
```